# Adding google map layer to basemap gallery arcgis 3.32

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I want to add google maps layer in my Arc Geographic Information System  application version 3.32.

I tried too much from many resources,but i did not have luck!!

Is any way i can add google map in Base Map Gallery or on my map as Base Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add the Google Maps basemap to the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. You can use the ArcGIS "World Street Map" basemap which is comparable. Example [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=3b93337983e9436f8db950e38a8629af). [More on ArcGIS Basemaps](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/data-location-services/data/basemaps-imagery#image2).